# Firebase not returning URL to Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a social media app. I have created the profile page. I connected it to my Firebase Database. But I want profile pic to be loaded from database.

In my database there is a profile pic url (which is firebase storage url) and I want to get it from database and represent the image on the profile pic.

And also I created 3 action requests. When user clicks on the photo 3 options available.

Choose new photo from gallery

take new photo using camera

show photo

because of that I also want my image to be passed to another view

here is some code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.size.width/2
    profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
    getImages()

}


func getImages(){
    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid==nil{
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logOutSegue", sender: self)
    } else {
        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        databaseRef.child("Users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                let ImageUrl = dict["Profpic"] as? String
                print(ImageUrl)
                let url = URL(string: ImageUrl!)
                print(url)
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                        if error != nil{
                            print(error?.localizedDescription)
                            return
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.profilePic?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }
                }).resume()
            }
        })
    }
}


@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.profilePic.image = image
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}



@IBAction func changePic(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Foto Kaynağı", message: "Bir kaynak seçin", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Kameranla yeni bir fotoğraf çek", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            print("Camera not available")
        }
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Galeriden yeni bir fotoğraf seç", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Fotoğrafı Göster", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showProfilePic", sender: self)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Geri Dön", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true,completion: nil)

}



@IBAction func saveClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storedImage = storageRef.child("Profile Pictures").child(imageName)
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profilePic.image!){
        storedImage.put(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            storedImage.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                if let urlText = url?.absoluteString{
                    self.databaseRef.child("Users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).updateChildValues(["ProfPic" : urlText], withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                        if error != nil{
                            print(error?.localizedDescription)
                            return
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your db-structure? Also does your observeSingleEvent trigger?

Comment: Are your print statements outputting the expected values? What is the problem here? You should make your problem and question more explicit.

Comment: My print statements returning nil. I mentioned it also

Comment: Could you post up your database structure? Are you sure you are at the right level in the database to retrieve the pic url?

Comment: I would add a a print(snapshot) statement as the *first* statement inside your closure. If you are not even getting that snapshot the rest of the code following the print doesn't matter. If you are not getting a snapshot then your reference is wrong *or* your rules are preventing the read from that node. I would personally build the ref like *let ref = databaseRef.child("Users")...* and then *print(ref)* followed by *ref.observerSingleEvent*. That way you can verify if the ref is pointing to the right location. If still nothing, include a snippet of your Firebase structure in your question.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your database structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for you. I use a dictionary to get the URL and then set the UIImageView to the image by the `sd_setImage` command.

Note: When using Firebase, you don't have to use a `URLSession` or `DispatchQueue`.

```
if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
       self.usernameLbl.text = dictionary["userName"] as? String
       self.genderLbl.text = dictionary["gender"] as? String
       self.ageLbl.text = dictionary["age"] as? String
       self.bioLbl.text = dictionary["bio"] as? String
       self.weightLbl.text = dictionary["weight"] as? String
       self.heightLbl.text = dictionary["name"] as? String

       let stringURL = NSURL(string: dictionary["profileImg"] as! String)
       self.profileImg.sd_setImage(with: stringURL as URL?)

            }
```

Comment: In order to use "sd_setImage" on ImageView, you need to use third party library called SDWebImage. Which also provides Image Caching support. Take a look at https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage @Semih Gençer